How do i change the size of a drawn shape in Python?
Firstly, i´m an absolte beginner in terms of coding and programs, so be patient please.
I´m using Thonny.
I have coded a simple shape of a skull and want to add a nose that´s just an upside-down heart. I already have the code for the heart too and it works just fine, however, my problem is that i want to change the size of that heart. It doesnt fit in the skull, it´s too big.
I´ve tried  decreasing the values but it obviously just deformed the shape.
Then i googled and tried finding something helpful, but all i could make out was "shapesize()" and that just works on the turtle itself, or i used it wrong.
Anything else was too complicated for me or not for Python.
I´m aware the solution is probably easy but i
don´t get it.
Please help out, i´m kinda stuck.
from turtle import *
speed(100)
hideturtle()
width(3.5)

lt(90)
circle(200,
       extent = 180) #Schädeldecke
lt(6)
circle(170,
       extent = 45) #WangenknochenI

rt(65)
fd(80)
lt(104)
fd(345) 
lt(104)
fd(80) #Kieferpartie 

rt(50)
circle(175,
       extent = 40)#WangenknochenII

penup()
goto(-210,50)
pendown()
circle(70,
       extent = 360)#AugenhöhleI

penup()
goto(-50,50)
pendown()
circle(70,
       extent = 360)#AugenhöhleII

penup()
goto(-197,-50)
pendown()
setheading(180)
def curve():
    for a in range(200):
        rt(1)
        fd(1)
lt(140)
fd(111.65)
curve()
lt(120)
curve()
fd(111.70)


Thanks. There's no builtin way to scale this--you'll need to redraw it using different points. Generally, avoid absolute commands like goto and setheading in favor of relative commands like forward, right, etc.

okay, so what exactly should i do? You said to redo it with different points, what do you mean by that? And should i try to code the shape more simple? Thanks for helping.

Well, you used a bunch of points to draw it in the first place, so make them all further apart to make the shape larger. For example, circle(200 could be circle(300. This would throw everything else off, so make everything else bigger too. Up to you on how you want to code the shape, but the simpler it is, the easier it will be to modify. If you use a size variable and make everything relative to the size, then you can more easily resize things by changing a single number, but this takes a bit of work to set up properly.


I´ve tried decreasing the values but it obviously just deformed the
shape.

For a simple image like this, you can scale it by doing the math.  In this example, I'm going to reduce it by 1/2.  First these two lines change their values by 1/2:
fd(111.65)
...
fd(111.70)

to instead be forward(55.35).  Then in curve(), we reduce the radius by 1/2, from 200 to 100, but we also have to double the amount of turn so that we reach the same end angle in half the steps:
def curve():
    for _ in range(100):
        right(2)
        forward(1)

Here's the complete solution:
from turtle import *

def curve():
    for _ in range(100):
        right(2)
        forward(1)

speed('fastest')
hideturtle()
width(4)

left(90)
circle(200, extent=180)  # Schädeldecke
left(6)
circle(170, extent=45)  # Wangenknochen I

right(65)
forward(80)
left(104)
forward(345)
left(104)
forward(80)  # Kieferpartie

right(50)
circle(175, extent=40)  # Wangenknochen II

penup()
goto(-210, 50)
pendown()
circle(70, extent=360)  # Augenhöhle I

penup()
goto(-50, 50)
pendown()
circle(70, extent=360)  # Augenhöhle II

penup()
goto(-197, -50)
pendown()
setheading(180)

left(140)
forward(55.35)
curve()
left(120)
curve()
forward(55.35)

exitonclick()



thank you for you efford and help! It helped me a lot.
